# matplotlib: how to return figure suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know you can return the title of an axis with ax.get_title(), but I cannot find a way to return the suptitle of a matplotlib figure. Is there something along the lines of fig.get_suptitle()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a figure `fig`'s suptitle text object

```
sup = fig._suptitle
```

To get the string content of the suptitle

```
label = fig._suptitle.get_text()
```

Comment: To get the suptitle as a string use ```fig._suptitle._text```.